# Denormalize data to calculate a metric in Keras

Tags: python, keras, normalization

I need to train a Keras model using `mse` as loss function, but i also need to monitor the `mape`.

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=[MeanAbsolutePercentageError()])
```

The data i am working on, have been previously normalized using `MinMaxScaler` from Sklearn. I have saved this scaler in a `.joblib` file. How can i use it to denormalize the data **only** when calculating the `mape`? The model still need to be trained with the normalized data.